# Access array posted with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using the following code to send a form to a php processor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something here on success
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
});
```

I presume that this sends the form to my php script with all the form values in json format but I then don't know how to then access this json and turn it back into the array i need to process in my PHP script.

Does anyone know how I access this variable in my processor script so I can process the data?

Also, what is the best way for me to view the data being posted so I can work out what to do with it, when I send the data the processor is obviously not displayed, is there a way to echo out/write the information received by the script to I can view it?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access to the json as an array called "$_POST" in your php.
for example, if you send the form as a json structured like this:

```
{
    "name":"userID",
    "psw":"password123"
}
```

in your php script there will be the variable $_POST with this structure:

```
$_POST = Array (
    "name" => "userID",
    "psw" => "password123"
)
```

**EDIT**

In a comment you asked me how to display the data received from the server,
that's quite simple,
in your php script just write this:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

so that you output the $_POST array in the json format,
then in your script write this:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), 
    function(data){ //"data" argument will contain the output from the server (that is the encoded $_POST array printed as json with the php code as showed above)

        console.log(data); //log data
    }
); //as you can see, I've deleted "json", becouse it's unuseful
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is there any way for me to view the data being posted, when I send the data the processor script is obviously not displayed, is there a way to write the information received by the script to a log so can view it?